# Is it possible to configure a link to open a page that contains an iframe, and have that iframe query an URL?

Tags: html, django, iframe, django-templates, href

I am setting up a registration confirmation email system.

The sign-up process usually takes place on my platform, and upon receiving the confirmation email, the link redirects to the same website the new user has signed-up on.

But the sign-up page I'm having trouble with is contained in an `iframe` on a website that I have no control over. I can only change what's inside of the `iframe`.

I would need the link sent through email to redirect to the page that contains the aforementionned `iframe`, while still activating the user in the `iframe`.

I work with django templates. I can change the body of the email, the registration page and the confirmation page, that's about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible.

However, in your HTML you can detect that you are in an iframe using javascript and use that to add a parameter to the form (e.g. a hidden input field) so that in Django you will *know* this comes from the iframe and you also know via the `Referer` header the address of the parent website.

Once you know that, you could make the email confirmation page tailored for the parent website, e.g. add a link back to it or make it look different than your normal confirmation page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I unfortunately need the whole sign-up process to happen on that foreign platform containing the iframe.

Comment: but the url of the iframe is controlled by the parent website, so without being able to change it, you can't control the url. Go back to your business/product owner and talk about alternatives, like my workaround.